# Evaluating the triple integral without using spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to evaluate the following triple integral:

$$\iiint_D(3+2xy)\,dV$$ over the solid hemispherical dome $D$ given by $x^2+y^2 +z^2 \le 4$ and $z \ge 0$.

This question is for the problem session, people has not learned spherical coordinates yet so  I have to find the  integral without using  them.

At first, I think we can start by writing $0 \le z \le2$ and find appropriate bounds for $x$ and $y$.

So, how can we evaluate this integral?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to start with that bound if you want to integrate with respect to $z$ first.

If you want to start by integrating with respect to $z$, the appropriate bounds would be $0$ and $\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$.

After that, we want to find the bounds for $x$ and $y$. When looking at the region in the $xy$ plane, we have a circle of radius $2$. Let's say we do the bounds for $y$ next. Looking at the circle, we have the bounds to be $-\sqrt{4-x^2}$ and $\sqrt{4-x^2}$.

This then leaves the bounds for $x$ to be $-2$ and $2$.

Answer (score 0):

without using spherical coordiantes.

$z = \sqrt {4-x^2-y^2}$

$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt {4-x^2}}^{\sqrt {4-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} 3 + 2xy\ dz\ dy\ dx$

Now, do you want to get tricky?

$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt {4-x^2}}^\sqrt {4-x^2}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} 3\ dz\ \ dy\ dx + \int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt {4-x^2}}^\sqrt {4-x^2}2xy\ dz\ dy\ dx$

$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt {4-x^2}}^\sqrt {4-x^2}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} 3\ dz\ dy\ dx $
is 3 times the volume of the hemisphere.

This function $f(x,y,z) = 2xy$ has a symmetry about the origin such that for every point $(x,y,z)$ in the region of integration , there is a corresponding point $(-x,y,z),$ such that $f(x,y,z) = -f(-x,y,z)$

$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt {4-x^2}}^\sqrt {4-x^2}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} 2xy\ dz\ dy\ dx = 0$

Comment: How did we find the bounds for $y$ and then $x$?